# Why is debugging with some exceptions enabled much slower?

Tags: java, scala, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm

Consider following code:

```
public class JMain {
    private final static int forLength = 6;

    private static void returnFromFor(int breakAt) {
        try {
            for (int j = 0; j < forLength; j++) {
                if (j == breakAt) {
                    throw new Throwable("break");
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int iterations = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            returnFromFor(i % forLength);
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(((Long) (end - start)).toString() + " ms");
    }
}
```

When I run this code in IntelliJ IDEA debugger with exception breakpoint enabled for `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, it runs very slow, about 1800 ms on my computer. When I run it with no exceptions breakpoints, or with breakpoint enabled for `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`, it is about 10x faster.

My questions are:

- why is debugging with `IllegalArgumentException` much slower than with `UnsupportedOperationException`?
- it the slowdown caused by the JVM debugger, or by IntelliJ?

The system I am running this on is:

- Windows x64
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64

*Note: the code above is demonstrating the issue I have with a complex Scala. If anyone is interested in the more natural Scala code demonstration, here it comes:*

```
object Main extends App {

  val forLength = 6
  def returnFromFor(breakAt: Int): Unit = {
    for (j <- 0 until forLength) {
      if (j == breakAt) return
    }
  }

  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val iterations = 100000
  for (i <- 0 until iterations) {
    returnFromFor(i%forLength)
  }
  val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
  println(s"Duration ${end-start} ms")

}
```

Comment: what about if you use the debugger simple print hello world, is it stil slow? If so, what is your OS?

Comment: @snr It is Winx64 - added system configuration into the question. As for simple printf demo, I am afraid I do not understand. There is no performance difference unless I enable exceptions breakpoints. When I enable them, there is no difference when no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: No, I mean when you enable breakpoint simple `System.out.println("test");`. Is the debugger still slow??

Comment: Enabling code breakpoints has no performance impact at all. It is only enabling some exceptions breakpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDEA does not set exception breakpoint until the target exception class is loaded.

`UnsupportedOperationException` is never loaded during a lifecycle of your program. That's why the program runs as fast as without breakpoints at all.

`IllegalArgumentException` is much more popular class, it is loaded somewhere inside JDK class library during JVM startup. In this case the exception breakpoint is indeed set, so that the debugger receives notifications about all exceptions thrown in your program.

Comment: I think this explains perfectly everything I see. Still I remain curious - is is possible to convince me somehow `IllegalArgumentException` is really loaded and the other one is not? I have tried placing breakpoints on all constructors of `IllegalArgumentException` and they did not trigger. I guess is it possible to load a class and not execute a constructor on it. Can this this be detected somehow? Or is this class loaded even before the debugger is attached to the process?

Comment: I confirm using `throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException()` early in my program makes the performance go down as you predicted when the corresponding exception breakpoint is enabled.

Comment: @Suma Run `java -verbose:class`. It's absolutely possible to load a class without creating any of its instances.

Comment: @apangig I did. To my surprise both `IllegalArgumentException` and `UnsupportedOperationException` were listed during app initialization, which is beyond me.